# Delphi Error Dataset not in Insert or Edit Mode, when in fact it is in Edit Mode

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tclientdataset, client-dataset

I googled a lot and found also some posts here in stack overflow about the error "Dataset not in Insert or Edit Mode", but all of them occurred properly when the trying to perform an action in a dataset which is not in edit or insert mode.

The strange problem I face here is that, even in edit mode, I'm getting this error.

This is my code:

```
 if DMMCI.TakeoffHistory.State in [dsInsert,dsEdit] then
    DMMCI.TakeoffHistory.Close;
```

When debugging, the "takeoddHistory.State" is "dsEdit" and so, it enters in the condition. However, at the "close" command it returns the error "Dataset not in Insert or Edit Mode".

Comment: Did you try looking at the call stack when the error happens? My guess is the act of closing the Dataset is probably triggering a field post after edit mode has already ended. Since you are in edit mode, you should call `Post()` or `Cancel()` before calling `Close()`.

Comment: Since your dataset is in edit mode there might be a field with changed values. Closing the dataset will then trigger a post for this dataset, but you just closed it, hence this message.  As Remy already suggested, do a Post or Cancel before closing